# Actual password visualisation in SQL table when using sha256

Tags: php, sql, sha256

I am training to secure the login process.

I have used sha 256 in the sign_up.php:

```
$username= check_input($_POST['username']);
$password= check_input($_POST['password']);
//the password is encrypted in sha256
$secure_sign_up_password = hash('sha256', $password);
```

and then of course in my users table in my SQL database, I can read:

- in the column 'login' the actual typed login 
  example: if somebody type 'michael', I will see 'Michael' in the SQL database
- in the column 'password' the actual typed login 
  example: if somebody type 'fruit', I will see the hashed value like 'e8bfab56c53980cd014206c8da2f8c9b9708eaacc61' in the SQL database

My question is simple but maybe a bit naive (I'm a newbie): I thought that I could still be able to read the actual password somewhere in my database and that hashing was only made to protect the password from getting intercepted and read while it was being sent. I never know, somebody might ask me to send him his real password. But the only thing I can see is the 'hashed' one in the password column.

- Is it made to be like this?
- Is it possible to visualize also the real password?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Never never never hold password in open format in database. If someone find exploit in system, he will be able to make any sql query and get users passwords. And hacker will be able to login into system as user, because he knows username and password
2. If user want restore password, make functionality for regenerating password. Never store password in plain text.
3. SHA256 is hash function. Mathematically it means - data can be "hashed" only in one way. I mean, that from hash you cannot restore data. You can read this http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash_function about hash functions and this about http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sha256 sha256
   Result: If someone crack you database and get username and password, he is unable to login into system. Because hacker have only hash data and can't get exactly password for login.
4. As i mentioned before, hash function can be "hash" data only in one way. But some hackers build VERY big data massive for some predefined algorithms. I mean, that they build hash tables for passwords. Such hash tables looks something like this:

```
    password    hash
    ------------------
    a           some_hash1
    b           some_hash2
    ...         .....
    qwerty      some_hash3
    some_data   some_hash3 -- yes, data can have collisions. See wiki about hash functions
```

And if hacker hacked you database and have such table, he able to restore password. For example, hacker get for admin user hash "some_hash3", then hacker search such hash in hash table, find that hash "some_hash3" have password "qwerty" and "some_data" and hacker will try to login with such passwords.
Result: Use salt. For nowadays hackers have such tables for 6 symbols passwords. But you can "suck" them in very simple technic: When you store password in database, add to password some value (salt) and get from such value hash:

```
// somewhere in code, where creating/updating users password

$password = hash('sha256', $salt.$password);
```

and when you will check password, use the same logic

Thanks

Answer (score 4):

If you would be able to "decode" those passwords, it wouldn't be a very safe system.  Once someone gained access to your database - they would be able to gain access to every ones passwords without them knowing...

If you have ever forgotten a password for a site (and we all have - don't deny it!), you'll recall that they usually* **don't** simply send you your password (in plain text) as a reminder to your email - they'll give you the opportunity to **reset** it.  This way (verifying usually through your email/phone number) they'll know that you are indeed the person who opened the account.

** If they send you your password in plain text that probably means they are storing it like that or in some other easily decrypted form.  This site is most likely not as secure as they would like to think...*

---

If you are interested in leaving yourself a "backdoor" of sorts to be able to access any of your users accounts, what you might think of doing is having a special login form from inside your administrator account, that allows you to use the encoded password to log in.  That means that you simply leave out the `hash('sha256', $password)` and pass the `$password` already encoded (which you extract from your database).  It's a bit hacky, and if you already have an administrator account then there wouldn't be much use to be able to log in as a different user because you are already **all powerful!**

Comment: Just to tack on a little detail - you probably want to use a stronger hashing algorithm than SHA256 these days.  Current popular opinion is that bcrypt() is the way to go.

Comment: It all depends on your application really.  For a simple low risk non-sensitive type of system, simply adding some salt on the end of a string might suffice.  Better safe than sorry though... What's that you were saying about `<Ctrl+T> wiki bcrypt`...

Answer (score 3):

This is by design.  **Nobody** should know what my password is, except for me.  Even you as a (insert fancy title here) should not know my password.  If I forget it, that's my problem, but your site should offer me a way to reset it.  Then when I reset, your site should store the hash once again.  The plain-text password should never be stored anywhere.

Answer (score 0):

sha256 hashes and other hashes are one way. See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cryptographic_hash_function. If you want to be able to decrypt what you write in the password fields in your database, you might want to use another approach.

Instead of creating a hash, you could encrypt with a key, that you do not share with your users. Look at http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.mcrypt.php. The key would be part of your code though, as it's symmetric encryption.

To do it really safe, try real PKI encryption (encrypt with a public key, decrypt with a private one). Look at php.net/manual/en/function.gnupg-encrypt.php or php.net/manual/en/book.openssl.php.

But as other here have said, such things are reasonably NOT done ;)